# Dynamically add the datacolumn of DataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

Guys i got a `dataColumn` already defined as

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Role" id="roleAdmin"  headerStyleName="myHeaderStyles">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
                <fx:Component>
                        <mx:VBox>
                                <mx:Text width="100%" text="{(data.role == 0)? 'Super Admin':((data.role == 1)? 'Admin': ((data.role == 2)? 'Regular User': 'Unknown'))}"/>
                        </mx:VBox>
                </fx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:DataGridColumn>
```

All I want to do is, to create this data dynamically depending upon the conditions I placed.Anyone can help me with the code what I should do and how can I add all these things.

Best Regards

Comment: What is wrong with this? The code seems to be alright

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. You will get logic how to handle dynamic columns with item renderer.

```
var cols:Array=new Array();
cols = dgDatagrid.columns;
var column:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn();
column.headerText = "Role";
column.width=170;
column.dataField="role";
column.setStyle('headerStyleName',myHeaderStyles);
column.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(MyRenderer);  
cols.push(column);
dgDatagrid.columns=cols;
```

MyRenderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MXDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
         >

    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" />
    </s:layout>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
    import mx.controls.DataGrid;
            import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridListData;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            import spark.events.TextOperationEvent;

            private var dg:DataGrid;
            private var dglistData:DataGridListData;


            override public function set data( value:Object ) : void 
            {
                super.data = value;
                if(value){
                    dglistData = listData as DataGridListData;
                    if(value[dglistData.dataField]){
txtText.text=((value[dglistData.dataField]) == 0)? 'Super Admin':(((value[dglistData.dataField]) == 1)? 'Admin': (((value[dglistData.dataField]) == 2)? 'Regular User': 'Unknown'))

                        }
                                            }
            }
]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:VBox>
<mx:Text width="100%" id="txtText"/>
 </mx:VBox>
</s:MXDataGridItemRenderer>
```

Comment: i already have a datagrid created but i just want to make this last column to be added dynamically :)

Comment: column.setStyle('headerStyleName',myHeaderStyles);
column.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(MyRenderer); are giving errors , They don't recognize myHeaderStyle and MyRenderer so i changed myHeaderStyle to "bold" but the problem now is how to create an itemrenderer and then place a vbox and textbox that will display datafield items

Comment: column.labelFunction="roleLabelFunction" gives error 
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type Function.

Comment: @umar Item renderer code is given in Myrenderer. use `myDataGrid.setStyle("headerStyleName", "myHeaderStyles");` and `column.labelFunction=roleLabelFunction`  try wthout quotes.

Comment: @umar i will suggest you that instead of trying to add dynamically why cant you set `visible` true or false for column depending upon your condition.?

Comment: thanks for giving that idea, i already did that, it just came late in my mind , thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a custom itemrenderer at all. This is a classic example of the use of a labelFunction.

First, write a label function as follows:

```
private function roleLabelFunction(data:Object, column:DataGridColumn):String {
    switch(data.role) {
        case 0: return 'Super Admin';
        case 1: return 'Admin';
        case 2: return 'Regular User';
        default: return 'Unknown';
    }
    //Some flex compilers show a compiler error if there is no return in the main function body, so this is the same as the default case
    return 'Unknown';
}
```

Then use this as the `labelFunction` of your datagridcolumn

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Role" id="roleAdmin"  headerStyleName="myHeaderStyles" labelFunction="roleLabelFunction">
```

Comment: +1 Nice explanation n example.. (I dint get the question correctly).

Comment: Well, M.S.Nayak is correct. i have a datagrid that has 6 columns, this column being the last one. I want some of the users to show this column mainly super admins but not to others.

Comment: WHAT?? that is so not what you made out to be in your question. You are going to have to elaborate more if you want to get a proper solution. maybe a sketch or screenshot would do..